# Deriving type class instance for ADT where some alternatives don't have type parameters

Tags: scala

I have a fairly involved ADT representing a small query language (mongodb, to be specific). A simplified version looks a bit like that:

```
sealed abstract class Query extends Product with Serializable

final case class Eq[A](field: String, value: A) extends Query
final case class And(queries: Seq[Query]) extends Query
case object None extends Query
```

I've declared `Query` without a type parameter since not all values actually have one - `None`, for example, is parameterless.

I also have a type class, `DocumentEncoder[A]`, that lets me turn any `A` into a `BsonDocument`.

The problem I'm running into is that `Query` needs a `DocumentEncoder`. Declaring one for each alternative is fairly trivial:

- `Eq[A]` writes itself, provided `A: DocumentEncoder`.
- `And` is very similar, if we assume that `Query` does have a `DocumentEncoder` instance.
- `None` simply encodes as the empty BSON document

What I'm struggling with is with writing a global `DocumentEncoder[Query]`. What I'd usually do is pattern match on each alternative, but in this case I'm stuck with `Eq[A]`: I'd need to express something like `case Eq[A: DocumentEncoder](field, value) => ...`, but this is, as far as I know, not possible - pattern matching happens at runtime, implicit resolution at compile time.

The solution I have, which I find very unsatisfactory, is storing a `BsonEncoder[A]` as a field of `Eq[A]`. This allows me to write something like:

```
implicit val queryEncoder: DocumentEncoder[Query] = DocumentEncoder.from {
  case e@Eq(field, value) => [...] e.encoder.encode(value) [...]
  [...]
}
```

I can't help but find this horrible, but can't find a more elegant solution. The only other thing I can think of is that my premise (`Query` should not have a type parameter) is flawed, but:

- having a type parameter, how would I go about writing `And`'s type declaration?
- is it ok to declare `None` as a `Query[Unit]` ?
- maybe in my case I could get away with always having a type parameter, but what about a theoretical more generic case where it's not possible?

Alright, ok, so I can think of another solution, but it feels rather like overkill: having `Query`'s type be a type member rather than a type parameter, and declaring a `Query.Aux` type alias that lifts the type member to a parameter (for implicit resolution). This sorts of feels like a "big boy"'s solution, though - I've seen it used in libraries like shapeless, and I somehow feel like my code or problems aren't yet of a level to require this kind of expert concepts.

Comment: If you provide an implicit `DocumentDecoder` for each type extending `Query`, why do you need a global `DocumentDecoder[Query]` at all? Implicit resolution is recursive.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov because I work with values of type Query. And, for example, takes a list of Query, not of more specific types

Comment: What if `And` took a type parameter with an upper bound of `Query`? `final case class And[A <: Query](queries: Seq[A]) extends Query`. Then implicit resolution would work for the underlying `A`s decoder. Or are you taking in different types of queries, both `And` and `Eq` inside the sequence? Then perhaps: `final case class And(queries: Seq[_ <: Query]) extends Query`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It's the second case - And must accept heterogenous queries. In your proposed solution, how do I get a DocumentEncoder[And[A]], since I don't know really know anything useful about A?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov finally understood what you meant and yes, you're right, I do not need a DocumentEncoder for Query. And needs to be tweaked to resemble something like an HList, but you're correct. Sorry it took me so long to realise what you meant.